# Database inspector from back-end

Tags: nodes

I'd like to know if there's a module that would allow users without administrator rights to inspect the database in order to see what nodes are using certain fields from specific content types.

Basically we want to get rid of some of the fields present on some of the content types we have on our platform but we're not sure how many nodes are using them and what values have been filled out from the back-end without having to dump the database.

Comment: Why not use the field report on the reports page of the admin?

Comment: Meaning... it will tell you what entity types are using which fields in order to audit them.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for some type of [WYSIWYG Reporting](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.reportingwysiwyg) as included in the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module ... Also, are you familiar with [this](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3614/39516)?